# Convert CHAR to int in SQL results in error

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm using Toad Data Point and am having an issue converting a Column. I'm trying to convert a Column called `Rep` which contains Char(2) into an integer. The table looks like this:

```
Row_ID   Rep   
1        00
2        01
3        02
4        03
```

I've tried the following:

```
drop table if exists #my_table
select Row_ID, CONVERT(INT, Rep) as new_col
into 
#my_table
from original_table
```

I tried `CAST(Rep as INT)` as well and both give me the error `Sybase Database Error: Data Exception -date type conversion is not possible`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sybase, something like this should work:

```
select Row_ID,
       (case when rep not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(rep as int) end) as new_col
into #my_table
from original_table;
```

The `case` expression is checking that the column `rep` only consists of digits -- that is, it has no non-digit character.  This does not handle negative numbers, but similar logic would handle that.